# How to handle a large table on SQLServer

Tags: sql-server-2008

There is a database on our server that has a 120GB backupfile. The server has limited diskspace and I cant even restore a second copy of that database.

There are mainly 2 tables in the databse that use 90% of the space.

Is there a way to exclude these 2 tables from the backup or have it in a second backup?

Comment: You could move the tables in question to their own filegroup and then backup only the other filegroup. The problem might be though to move the tables to the second filegroup. It might take up more diskspace while moving than you have available.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use export table structures and use `bcp` to export the data from the tables you want to backup. 
But don't forget that you have an *inconsistent backup*, you should backup the whole database - may it be full or differential.

Start a project to add additional storage to the server - a SAS HBA and a JBOD should not break the bank. If upper management does not approve, put in balance losing the data.